# "This is not a login form" is being stored when updating a password in keycloak theme

Tags: redhat, keycloak

At our project we got a problem with the Keycloak theme. The Keycloak theme developers placed 2 html input boxes that are hidden in the [Keycloak](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-dev/2016-April/006973.html) theme:

`<input type="text" readonly value="this is not a login form" style="display: none;">
 <input type="password" readonly value="this is not a login form" style="display: none;">`

They did this to prevent the browser to fill the current password. But when you update your password, the password manager of the browsers tries to store "this is not a login form" as either username and password.

Anyone an idea how to prevent the password manager to store "this is not a login form" when updating an users password or is this intentional

[screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6dsi.png)

Comment: Got the same issue. Have you managed to fix this ?

Comment: No, we don't got a response yet.

Answer (score 0):

I created my own theme and added jQuery. Then i wrote this little rascal:

```
$(function() {
  $("input#username").on("change", function() {
    var currentVal = $("input#username").val();
    if(currentVal === "this is not a login form") {
      $("input#username").val("");
    }
  });
});
```